# Frequently send object by Socket

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, pack

I'm tring to develop the WinForm with C#. This application must capture desktop frequently and send it to remote server via socket. How can I pack on client and unpack in server these Images for compress image size higher speed in transfer?

Is it possible? If yes get me any idea or solution.

Thanks so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Use of Background Worker , I Had similar problem and i resolve it by one timer and one Backgrond Worker .

If this idea is not good solution put your code here .